# OpenStreetMap Bash / CGI Script

Tags: bash, cgi, openstreetmap

I am trying to build a Bash CGI script, that takes in coordinates as parameters from the URL and uses osmosis to extract the map and the splitter and mkgmap to make the map, so that it can be opened with Qlandkarte.

My problem being is that when I type `wget localhost/cgi-bin/script.pl?top=42&left=10&bottom=39&right=9&file=map.osm` the Linux terminal reads the file with the coordinates.

How can I make wget just activate the script so it takes the coordinates and executes the commands? And also when the map is created at the end how can a return the file that was created by the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
TOP=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | grep -oE "(^|[?&])top=[0.0-9.0]+" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | head -n1`
LEFT=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | grep -oE "(^|[?&])left=[0.0-9.0]+" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | head -n1`
BOTTOM=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | grep -oE "(^|[?&])bottom=[0.0-9.0]+" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | head -n1`
RIGHT=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | grep -oE "(^|[?&])right=[0.0-9.0]+" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | head -n1`
FILE=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | grep -oE "(^|[?&])file=[^&]+" | sed "s/%20/ /g" | cut -f 2 -d "="`
    
$(sudo osmosis --read-xml file=bulgaria.osm --bounding-box top=$TOP left=$LEFT bottom=$BOTTOM right=$RIGHT --write-xml file=$FILE)
$(sudo java -Xmx900m -jar splitter.jar --max-nodes=110000 $FILE)
$(sudo java -ea -Xmx900m -jar mkgmap.jar --tdbfile --route -c template.args)
    
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
```

Comment: You don't need to use `$(...)` on the three commands run by `sudo`. Just `sudo osmosis ...` etc. is sufficient.

Comment: I think the shell is expanding the '&' chars in your URL as instructions to 'background the command text that precedes this & char'. So try quoting your whole URL like `wget 'localhost/cgi-bin/script.pl?top=42&left=10&bottom=39&right=9&file=map.osm' `. Good luck.

Comment: Also, do you have a perl script, or are you naming your `bash` script 'script.pl'?

Comment: I will try it. No I just named the script like that on the forum. I dont have it in Perl, not too familiar with CGI Scripting. Thanks for the information hopefully it will work out.

Comment: Why do you want to write a CGI script if you are executing it locally anyway? A normal shell script seems sufficient.